# Does IBM Worklight 6.0 support Rich Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I know that IBM Worklight 6.0 server supports the Basic Push Notification, and there are sample codes available on IBM Worklight site to implement it.

I want to know if the IBM Worklight server supports the Rich Push Notification to be sent to the GCM or APN from the Worklight server.

Sample code to send the Push Notification to Mobile with sound is supported as given below:

```
WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
      badge: 1,
      sound: "alarma.wav",
      activateButtonLabel: "ClickMe",
      alert: notificationText,
      payload: {
          foo : 'bar'
      }
  });
```

I want to check if the payload can support to send the Rich Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight push notifications for Android:

- Support Basic GCM Notifications (push notifications)
- Support cloud sync notifications
- Support [notifications priority](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Priority) (starting [MFP 6.3](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html?cp=SSHS8R_6.3.0%2F9-1-0-1-6&lang=en))
- Does not support [Rich Notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications) - *note that Rich Notifications is **not** the same as push notifications*
- Does not support creating custom notification views (you'll need to override the default and implement it on your own)

Worklight push notifications for iOS:

- Support Basic Notifications
- Support Silent Notifications (starting MFP 6.3)
- Support Interactive Notifications (starting MFP 6.3)
- Support Background notifications (starting MFP 6.3)
- Does not support Local Notifications

You are encouraged to [submit feature requests](http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help).